# SSRS Dynamically change Datasource connection String

Tags: reporting-services

I want to modify the connection String of a Shared Data Source on a report Server. the reason is, every week we deploy new data on the server, so I am planning to deploy new database, test it and modify the datasource so that it than connect to new database, then remove the old database.

Can anyone help me in the regards.

I tried to use this post: [Updating Shared data source connection string programmatically](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/b9874ec7-f2da-40a1-9dc1-3523c0e81741)

but I can not create ReportingService2005 object as dll is missing to which this object points.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReportingServices2005 is not a dll, it's a webservice

The URL is formatted as below for most 2005 instances:

```
https://<<Report Server Name>>/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx
```

If you add the web reference the solution you have should work

Comment: Thanks this is working very well with a ASP.NET Web application, but when I did the same in Winforms application, I can not see "ReportingService2005" object, its missing, the reason why I wanna run using winforms application, because I want to execute this code through SSIS pacakge every week.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to creating a custom application to do this is to use the rs.exe utility to execute the code as a script.

[Scripting with the rs Utility and the Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms152874%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)